# Memory / Optimization concern

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, memory-management

I'm working at a complex script which could be processing upto 500,000 records. Here's my question.

Basically my code will parse a text file to get each of those 500,000 or so records. Each record will have a category, my code will need to check if a new record in the `categories` table had been created for that category during that particular processing, and if not, it will create that record.

So I have 2 options:

1) I store an array of keys=>values containing category name and ID, so I could do this:

```
if (array_key_exists($category,$allCategories))
   $id=$allCategories[$category];
else
{
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (procId,category) 
                       VALUES ('$procId''$category')");
   $id=mysql_insert_id();
   $allCategories[$category]=$id;
}
```

2) Each time this text file is processed, it will get its own process ID. So rather than checking the `$allCategories` variable which could grow to have 100,000+ entries, I could do this:

```
SELECT id FROM categories WHERE procId='$procId' AND category='$category'
```

The downside here is that this query will be run for each of the 500,000+ records. Whereas the disadvantage of holding all the categories in an array is that I could run out of memory or the server could crash.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just keep a list of the ids that you've already inserted?  If they are integer ids, that's 4 bytes each times 100,000 entries would use only about 400K of memory.

ETA:

To avoid storing the category name, hash the name and store the hash.  With a 128 bit MD5 hash, that's 16 bytes per hash or only about 1.6MB of memory + overhead.

Comment: But i'd also need to store the category names, which are in a string such as "Category A", "Category B", "Long name category C", etc. So it could add up. But if its a better option than doing a query each time, i might go with it

Comment: PHP takes about 68 bytes to store an integer. It isn't C. It stores everything in a C struct called a ZVal and... well you can't take sizeof(int) from C and assume it translates to PHP.

Comment: @James - yeesh, I knew PHP would have extra overhead, but I had no idea it was that bad :)

Comment: Eric, which hash system do you recommend? Md5?

Answer (score 1):

One idea will be to add a constraint on table so duplicate inserts are rejected by database. 
Then just keep inserting all records and let the db do the checking.

Comment: Good idea but each of the records need to be linked to the appropriate category ID in the database. Also, there might be more than 1 record with the same category name but a different userId or procId (process id)

Comment: You can define a composite unique key on (category,userid,procid) so database will only reject inserts when exact same combination of these column values is already present in the table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `categories` (                                                
              `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',                              
              `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',                                  
              `proc_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',                                  
              UNIQUE KEY `UniqueCategoryUserProc` (`category_id`,`user_id`,`proc_id`)  
            ) TYPE=InnoDB

Answer (score 1):

Given that your average category name is 30 bytes, you'd only need 30 * 500000 bytes = 15000000 bytes = 15000 kilobytes = 1.5 megabytes.

I think you have this much memory.